# Does git fetch get all branches in remote into local?

Tags: git, github

If I do a `git fetch` in local, then remove branches in github, I still have a copy of these deleted branches in local, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. 
In order to update local fetched branches with the remote ones, you have to do `git fetch --prune`.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: `git fetch --prune` means do `git checkout branchXXX; git pull` on every branch?

Comment: @Sato: I don't think this is a good explanation.
First, because you have to make `git pull` before in order to checkout a remote branch.
Secondly, because you couldn't rightly handle deleted branch with the command sequences you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It does.

As the documentation says..

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more
>   other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their
>   histories. Remote-tracking branches are updated (see the description
>   of  below for ways to control this behavior).
>
> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is
>   also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that
>   you are interested in. This default behavior can be changed by using
>   the --tags or --no-tags options or by configuring
>   remote..tagOpt. By using a refspec that fetches tags explicitly,
>   you can fetch tags that do not point into branches you are interested
>   in as well.
>
> git fetch can fetch from either a single named repository or URL, or
>   from several repositories at once if  is given and there is a
>   remotes. entry in the configuration file. (See git-config[1]).
>
> When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be
>   used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current
>   branch.
>
> The names of refs that are fetched, together with the object names
>   they point at, are written to .git/FETCH_HEAD. This information may be
>   used by scripts or other git commands